# Should ffmpeg questions on SuperUser be migrated here?

Tags: discussion, migration

[A lot of questions about ffmpeg](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ffmpeg) get asked on SuperUser. Should they be migrated to Video Production?

Most of them are on-topic here, more than they are for SU in my opinion. Particularly the ones that are solely dealing with the *use* of ffmpeg, rather than questions about installing it or running it on a server etc.

Should this discussion be started on SU meta too?

Comment: There are a lot of ffmpeg/avconv questions on Stack Overflow, and while some of them are about the library or the code, most are about the encoding, and they get closed and downvoted there. It is them that we should be trying to save.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think we actively need to migrate them if they are asked on SU as long as they get answered there.  A lot of basic FFMPEG questions are really more man page oriented than video production oriented.

Comment: Agreed. If they get no answers there, then let's consider migrating.

Answer (score 1):

These questions would have to be declared largely off topic before you should consider annexing questions in bulk from *another* community (and all the rep/privileges that go with those posts).

See [**Respect the community – your own, and others’**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/)

Answer (score 0):

I've seen, and answered, a good deal of ffmpeg question on StackOverflow as well. Sometimes they cover topics such as encoding for devices and streaming protocols.

I'm a bit at loss concerning those questions as they're pretty much off topic on StackOverflow, ServerFault and VideoProduction.

I've pushed a new proposal for a Streaming Q&A on Area51, seeing how streaming is becoming mainstream (pun intended).

If you think a new Q&A is in order you can leave feedback here:
http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/85456/streaming?referrer=ZrStC2p5A_kkkTHdHXGQPA2